# SQL: Where result of 2 SUM() is greater than 0 in another table

Tags: sql

Here's the scenario:

```
 ---------------
|Table A        |
|---------------|
|tba_id tba_name|
|1      Item A  |
|2      Item B  |
 ---------------
 -------------------------------------
|Table B                              |
|-------------------------------------|
|tbb_id tbb_tbaid tbb_qtyIn tbb_qtyOut|
|1      1         5         0         |
|2      2         4         0         |
|3      2         7         0         |
|4      1         0         5         |
 -------------------------------------
```

Table A is where I store the item details. 
Table B is where I store the quantity in and out of Table A. 
I would like to retrieve all of Table A that has a quantity greater than 0 in Table B through a single SQL query line. Which means it would be something like: sum of qtyIn - sum of qtyOut > 0.

Comment: what's your DBMS and its version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
select a.tba_name from TableA a where exists(
select * from TableB b where a.tba_id=b.tbb_tbaid group by b.tbb_tbaid having 
(sum(tbb_qtyIn)-sum(tbb_qtyOut))>0);
```

Answer (score 3):

use aggregation

```
select a.tba_name
 from tabla a join tableb b on a.tba_id=b.tbb_tbaid
group by a.tba_name
having (sum(tbb_qtyIn)-sum(tbb_qtyOut))>0
```

Comment: I have a question: What's the purpose of the group by that you used? Can I not use b.tbb_tbaid instead to group the records in Table B by the id of the Table A? I tried running your query in the sqlyog and it worked but I want to understand how it worked.

Comment: @jr.prog learn about aggregation you will get the idea and you accepting the answer which is answered 5 minutes later than my answer :)

Comment: Both answers worked however, I still do not understand why you chose "group by a.tba_name". If for example there was a third record in Table A with the same name to "Item B" but different id (tba_id = 3, tba_name = Item B), from what I understand, your query will group that two records as one because they have the same name. Both their quantity movement in Table B will be grouped together as well. Am I wrong with that analogy?

Comment: please do let me know as I genuinely want to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use single `sum()` :

```
select a.tba_id, a.tba_nam
from a inner join
     b
     on a.tba_id = b.tbaid
group by a.tba_id, a.tba_nam
having sum(b.tbb_qtyIn - b.tbb_qtyOut) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to write this as:

```
select a.tba_name
from TableA a
where (select sum(b.tbb_qtyIn) - sum(b.tbb_qtyOut)
       from TableB b
       where a.tba_id = b.tbb_tbaid
      ) > 0;
```

A scalar subquery to calculate the net amount just seems like the most direct solution.